# Wordpress: Advanced Custom Fields Select Users with higher role levels not possible

Tags: wordpress, advanced-custom-fields, user-roles

I have a ACF Relational User Field where on can select a user. But, it only displays the users with a lower role level. I need to be able to choose at least same level roles.

Is this a WP thing or ACF? Anyway to change that behaviour?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a acf plugin problem. The roles displayed in the select boxed were acquired with get_editable_roles(). Whereas I needed it to display the selected roles allways.